# How to exclude middleware running on _next/data files in Next 13? Locale redirects are applied to _next/data

Tags: next.js, middleware, vercel, next.js13

Our Next app uses i18n for language translations. We have the URL setup as ourdomain.com/, ourdomain.com/es, ourdomain.com/fr, ourdomain.com/it etc. We are hosting the site on Vercel.

If a user switches country on the site we drop a cookie to remember their country choice.

We use a midddleware.ts file to then redirect a user to their chosen country if that cookie is present. So the next visit for example middleware redirects them to say the /es site if they previously chose that site and the cookie exists.

The problem is that it looks like _next/data/ .json files are being redirected also. I can see those URLs have 307 redirects to the cookie language. This results in the content .json files not being loaded and the app crashes.

For example, if the redirect would take the user to the FR site, then loading other language files like ES does not work as _next/data is redirected.

This URL:

```
/_next/data/xxxxx/es.json
```

Is redirected to the following which does not work:

```
/_next/data/xxxxx/esindex.json
```

Various methods documented online to exclude _next from middleware no longer seem to work in Next 13.

```
url.pathname.startsWith('/_next')
```

url no longer contains pathname

```
request.headers.get('referer').indexOf("/_next/data")
```

Initially I thought the referer in the header would work but it's not always working on Vercel, I can still see some _next/data files redirecting.

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)',
    '/',
  ],
};
```

matcher is not working on vercel for _next/data. Perhaps its because what this page states "*Even when using path matching, Edge Middleware runs on all /_next/data/ requests for getServerSideProps and getStaticProps pages for the sake of consistency.*"
https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-middleware/middleware-api

Here is my middleware file, but _next/data is being redirected on Vercel still. The conditional checks for _next and the matcher do not always work on _next/data, because some of the requests are still redirected.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export default function middleware(request)
{
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const referer = request.headers.get('referer');

    if(
        (referer && referer.indexOf("/_next/data") >= 0) ||
        url.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
        url.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
        PUBLIC_FILE.test(url.pathname)
    )
    {
        return
    }

    const response = NextResponse.next();
    const { origin } = request.nextUrl
    let locale = request.nextUrl.locale;

    // If cookie exists, and does not match locale, redirect
    let country = request.cookies.get('country')?.value;
    if(country)
    {
        country = country.split('|')[0];
        if (country && locale && country != locale)
        {
            return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/${country}/`)
        }
    }
    return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)',
    '/',
  ],
};
```

Comment: did you try to remove '/' from matcher?

Comment: Yes that was not originally on there and I still had the issue. The reason that is there because at one point I thought middleware was not running on the home page and I found an article that said so and to add that, but I am not sure thats the case anymore maybe I was confused. Either way, removing the home page from matcher does not prevent middleware running on _next/data files for me.

Comment: remove this .*\\..* too. if problem persist provide your code in code sandbox or stackblitz, so i can work on the code

Comment: your matcher should look like below.

Comment: matcher: [
    '/((?!api|static|_next).*)'
  ],